# How is PCA applied to (one-hot encoded) DNA sequence data?

Tags: pca, one-hot-encoding, sequence

I realize some questions have been asked already about one-hot encoding for PCA. The answer seems to be along the lines of 'The PCA will run, but does not necessarily make sense.'

However, I have a question regarding the application of PCA on **one-hot encoded sequence data**. For example, in [this paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-019-55253-0), the authors claim to first one-hot encode DNA sequences, and then apply PCA on *some* resulting matrix. I'm trying to understand this paper (I'm looking to apply a similar strategy for a different kind of sequence), but I don't see to what matrix they actually apply PCA.

The part I don't understand is this: If we one-hot encode using the categories "$a,t,g,c,\_$" (as stated in the paper)

a sequence $\{gaatc\}$ becomes:
$\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

a sequence $\{aagctt\}$ becomes:
$\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}$

Meaning every sample is now a matrix. In "normal" PCA every sample is a vector, which we stack together into the  matrix of which we determine the coveriance, etc.

So what is being done in case of one-hot encoded sequence data? How are these sample-matrices combined such that we can determine a (useful) covariance matrix?

Answer (score 0):

The paper is incorrect in applying Principal Component Analysis (PCA) to boolean data since PCA implicitly minimizes a squared loss function, which is not always appropriate for not real-valued data. "[A Generalization of Principal Components Analysis to the Exponential Family](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2001/hash/f410588e48dc83f2822a880a68f78923-Abstract.html)" by  Collins et al. goes into detail.

Boolean data would be more appropriately modeled with [Multiple Correspondence Analysis (MCA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_correspondence_analysis).

Comment: I understand that PCA may not be appropriate for categorical data. However, I am interested in seeing what they actually (mathematically) do here. The results they claim seem at least interesting, if not useful.

Comment: Your question may be better answered on https://stats.stackexchange.com/.  https://datascience.stackexchange.com tends to focus on correctly applying the most appropriate technique.

Comment: IMO you jump too quickly to "not appropriate", without understanding what the authors are doing.